# Remove folder names from the URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am stuck in here with htaccess. I've searched and tried many tutorials and problem solutions but couldn't achieve what I want.

I want to remove folder names from the website link. My htaccess file is in the root directory i.e "testing"

What my link looks like:

```
http://localhost/testing/sub/test.php
```

What I want:

```
http://localhost/test.php
```

Following is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /(.*) /testing/sub/$1    [L]
```

Comment: "My htaccess file is in the root directory i.e 'testing'" - This is a bit misleading, since `testing` would seem to be a subdirectory off the root directory. Is `/testing/sub/test.php` your actual file location? In which case, your links should actually look like `/test.php`, not `/testing/sub/test.php` as you state. Only then do you internally rewrite the request back to `/testing/sub/test.php` (which is what your code is trying to do).

Comment: Yes. "xampp/testing/sub/test.php" is my file location.
I want my url to look like "localhost/test"

Comment: Then the first thing to do is change the URL in your application. This isn't something you do in .htaccess (unless you need to correct indexed or linked to URLs). When the URL "looks" the way you want, _then_ use .htaccess to internally rewrite the request to the real URL.

Comment: First you say you want the URL to be `localhost/test.php`, and then you say you want it to be `localhost/test`. Which one is it?

Comment: localhost/test.php
Can I use str_replace to replace the url segment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this line in your root .htaccess

**RewriteRule ^test.php$ /testing/sub/test.php**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to go to the folder that contains all the files for your site .  For example if the folder is named  " site1 "  go to it  form your cpanel  copy all the files to your  Public_html  folder

one way to do that  is once you locate the folder that has your site files and you are  looking at them ,
click on select  all to select all the files  or if you do not see select all 
click on the first file in the folder  it should be highlighted
then scroll down to the very last file of the folder 
press the shift button on your keyboard  and click the last file 
now everything  should be highlighted. 
if not repeat the process again 
until everything is highlighted .

right click 
and click on copy

on the little popup window on the bottom
you should see copy file to 
make sure the folder you're copying the files to is 
/public_html
 then click on the copy files button on the lower right corner of the popup window .

all of your files should now be in the pulic_html folder
 you need to now change your configuration.php file 
right click on  and click on edit  once the popup window opens click on edit again 
it should open in your browser 
look for the code line that says :

public $live_site = 'http://vivendishop.com';

if your domain name has a /folder 
remove it  and save

that should do it  hope that works 
for you