# how to remove folder name from url using htaccess or php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change the URL from:

```
http://example.com/folder/name-file.php
```

To:

```
http://example.com/name-file.php
```

**basically i want to hide url folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^folder(/.*|)$ $1 [L,NC]  
</IfModule>
```

I have tried a lot but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668612/remove-directory-from-url-with

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679002/remove-folder-names-from-the-url-using-htaccess

Comment: If not: if you tried a lot, share more than a single attempt